# what is soap in magento? what is use of it?what is use of soap/xml-RPC-user?

Tags: magento, soap

```
what is use of soap/xml-RPC-user and soap/xml-RPC-roles?
```

in system menu there is one menu item web services contains 4-5 options like soap/xml-RPC-user and soap/xml-RPC-roles. 
what is use of it? how to use that?

Answer (score 0):

The [original Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) was implemented both in SOAP and XML-RPC. SOAP and XML-RPC are well known technologies for creating functions, classes, and methods client-programmers may call over HTTP. Explaining them in greater detail is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.

The User and Roles menus are the for the authentication portion of the Magento API.  To authenticate the API, you call a login method, passing in a username and password. You setup this user name and password in the Users menu you mentioned.

Each user you setup has access to a "role".  Roles determine which API functions a user may call.  You setup the roles in the Roles menu you mentioned.  You assign a role to a User when you're editing it in the User section you mentioned.

In newer versions of Magento these sections are explicitly labeled with SOAP/XML-RPC to differentiate them from the newer REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

At first you'll need to know the use of web services. To acquire basic knowledge of web services,soap and xml-rpc read below url

```
http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=1152
http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/04/rest-and-soap-web-services-analogy/
```

After getting basic knowledge of web services read how to use it in magento from below url

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/introduction
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/
```